change text language in flutter
i'm trying to change flutter app language
widgets are reversed but words remain the same lng
i must hot restart my app to change lng
 BlocBuilder<LocaleCubit, LocaleState>(
        buildWhen: (previous, current) => previous != current,
        builder: (context, state) {
          print("hna LocaleState ${state.locale}");
          return MaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            theme: appTheme(),
            locale: state.locale,
            onGenerateRoute: AppRoutes.onGenerateRoute,
            supportedLocales: AppLocalizationsSetup.supportedLocales,
            localeResolutionCallback:
                AppLocalizationsSetup.localeResolutionCallback,
            localizationsDelegates:
                AppLocalizationsSetup.localizationsDelegates,
          );
        },
      )

this local cubit
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../../../../core/di/injection_container.dart';
import '../../../../core/usecase/usecase.dart';
import '../../../../core/utils/app_strings.dart';
import '../../domain/usecases/change_lang.dart';
import '../../domain/usecases/get_saved_lang.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'locale_state.dart';

class LocaleCubit extends Cubit<LocaleState> {
  late final ChangeLangUseCase changeLangUseCase;
  late final GetSavedLangUseCase getSavedLangUseCase;

  LocaleCubit(
      {required this.changeLangUseCase, required this.getSavedLangUseCase})
      : super(const ChangeLocaleState(locale: Locale(AppStrings.arabicCode)));

  Future<void> getSavedLang() async {
    print("hna getSaved");
    final response = await getSavedLangUseCase.call(sl<NoParams>());
    response.fold((failure) => LocaleError(msg: failure.message), (value) {
      emit(ChangeLocaleState(locale: Locale(value)));
    });
  }

  Future<void> _changeLang(String langCode) async {
    final response = await changeLangUseCase.call(langCode);
    response.fold((failure) => LocaleError(msg: failure.message), (value) {
      emit(ChangeLocaleState(locale: Locale(langCode)));
    });
  }

  String get getCurrentLang => state.locale!.languageCode;
  void toEnglish() async{
    print("hna toEnglish");
    await _changeLang(AppStrings.englishCode);
  }

  void toArabic() {
    print("hna toArabic");
    _changeLang(AppStrings.arabicCode);
  }
}

the ui is rebuilt when i change lng but text not
i'm using import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../../config/locale/app_localizations.dart';
extension TranslationHelper on BuildContext {
  String translate(String key) {
    try {
      
      return AppLocalizations.of(this)!.translate(key)!;
    } catch (_) {
      return key;
    }
  }
}

to cahnge lng
